# Imagenes superpuestas responsives ¿Posibilidades?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, responsive

Estoy jugando con el posicionamiento de imagenes responsives ( usando a nuestro amigo bootstrap) y quiero hacer una imagen base , como la del ejemplo
en la que tengo un div con una imagen de fondo y sobre este varios div con imagenes ( con transparencia).

Todo ello responsive y siempre posicionado sobre el div principal , os pongo una foto de la intencion :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien :

- ¿Se puede hacer el fondo de un div responsive ?
- ¿Como posiciono una imagen encima de otra ? Me refiero , si yo ahora mismo quisiera poner una carta encima de la otra, ¿ Como seria posible respetando los requisitos anteriores ?

Muchas gracias.

```css
#color{
 background-image: url("https://preview.ibb.co/dmmFJK/Tablero1080.png");
 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    /* background:no-repeat fixed center;  */
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 max-width:1080px;
 max-height:660px;
 margin-top:30px;
 

 
 
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Bj</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="container" id="color">

    <div class="row justify-content-center">
   <div class="col-4" id="color2">
     1 of two columns
     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/mr7cXe/AS_co.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
   </div>
   <div class="col-4" id="color1">
     2 of two columns
     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/mr7cXe/AS_co.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
   </div>
    </div>
    
    
  </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé si entendí bien lo que quieres pero preparé un ejemplo que tal vez pueda ayudarte.

Primero, el `HTML` que contiene:

- Un `Div` Contenedor.
- Un segundo `Div` que contendrá las cards.
- 2 `divs` que representan las cards.
- 3 elementos `<button>` que estarán por fuera del contenedor.

  ```
  <div class="container">
      <div id="main-div">
      <div class="card position-card1" id="card1">card 1</div>
      <div class="card position-card2" id="card2">card 2</div>
  </div>

  <div id="botones">
      <button id="btn1">card 2 over card 1</button>
      <button id="reset">reset</button>
      <button id="btn2">card 1 over card 2</button>
  </div>
  ```

---

Ahora un poco de CSS:

En el Div contenedor, le doy un **display:flex** para dar solución a tu pregunta de hacerlo responsivo.

```
.container{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;   
}
```

---

El `#main-div` es el contenedor de las 2 cards, por lo tanto le doy `positión: relative` para poder ubicar las cards dentro de el.

```
#main-div{
    position: relative;
    min-width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgb(255,240,0);
    border: 4px solid rgb(255,200,0);
}
```

---

Ahora le damos estilos a las cards. Las dos tendran un `position: absolute` para poder jugar con las coordenadas. El resto es maquillaje.

```
.card{
    position: absolute;
    width: 60px;
    height: 100px;
    background: rgb(0,255,0);
    border: 2px solid rgb(0,200,100);
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

---

Cada `card` se posiciona proporciolamente en su contenedor padre. (Recuerda que tienen `position: absolute` y se centran verticalmente.

```
.position-card1{
    top: 50px;
    left: 60px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.position-card2{
    top: 50px;
    left: 180px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

---

Ahora para poder sobreponer una card encima de la otra, creo 3 botones para lanzar los eventos con javascript un botón para sobreponer la `card2` sobre la `card1` otro para disparar el efecto contrario.  y por último un botón `reset` para reiniciar las posiciones.

```
.over-card2{
    top: 46px;
    left: 176px;
    z-index: 100;
}

.over-card1{
    top: 46px;
    left: 56px;
    z-index: 100;
}

#botones{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;  
}

#reset,
#btn1{
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

---

Por último, el código Javascript:

recupero los elementos del dom (los 3 botones) en 3 variables:

```
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
var btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');
var reset = document.getElementById('reset');
```

Programo los botones :

```
btn1.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let card2 = document.getElementById('card2');
    card2.classList.replace('position-card2','over-card1');
});

btn2.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let card1 = document.getElementById('card1');
    card1.classList.replace('position-card1','over-card2');
});
```

*La clase `over` se adiciona para que siempre se superposicione con `z-index` *

---

Y por último el botón que restaura las `cards` a la posición inicial.

```
reset.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let reset = document.getElementById('reset');
    card1.className = 'card position-card1';
    card2.className = 'card position-card2';
});
```

*Adjunto el código ya completo y además, Puedes Probar el efecto aquí abajo. Espero te sirva o por lo menos te de ideas para mejorarlo y muy seguramente con JQuery salga con menos lineas. Bendiciones !*

```js
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
var btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');
var reset = document.getElementById('reset');

btn1.addEventListener('click', function(){
  let card2 = document.getElementById('card2');
  card2.classList.replace('position-card2','over-card1');
});

btn2.addEventListener('click', function(){
  let card1 = document.getElementById('card1');
  card1.classList.replace('position-card1','over-card2');
});

reset.addEventListener('click', function(){
  let reset = document.getElementById('reset');
  card1.className = 'card position-card1';
  card2.className = 'card position-card2';
});
```

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;   
}

#main-div{
  position: relative;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: rgb(255,240,0);
  border: 4px solid rgb(255,200,0);
}

.card{
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgb(0,255,0);
  border: 2px solid rgb(0,200,100);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}

.position-card1{
  top: 50px;
  left: 60px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.position-card2{
  top: 50px;
  left: 180px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.over-card2{
  top: 46px;
  left: 176px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.over-card1{
  top: 46px;
  left: 56px;
  z-index: 100;
}

#botones{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;  
}

#reset,
#btn1{
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="main-div">
      <div class="card position-card1" id="card1">card 1</div>
      <div class="card position-card2" id="card2">card 2</div>
  </div>  
</div>

<div id="botones">
  <button id="btn1">card 2 over card 1</button>
  <button id="reset">reset</button>
  <button id="btn2">card 1 over card 2</button>
</div>
```